# UnboundLocalError at /tweets local variable 'searchtext' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, api, data-analysis, tweepy

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
@login_required(login_url='login')
def tweetsPageView(request):

    twitter_client = TwitterClient()
    
    tweet_analyzer = TweetAnalyzer()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        searchform = Searchform(request.POST)
        if searchform.is_valid():
            searchtext ='%s' %(searchform.cleaned_data['search'])
            searchform.save()
    
    api = twitter_client.get_twitter_client_api()
    tweets =api.user_timeline(screen_name =searchtext, count = 50 )
    df = tweet_analyzer.tweet_to_data_frame(tweets)
    html_file =df.to_html()
```

Comment: i keep getting this error local variable 'searchtext' referenced before assignment

Comment: trying to search for a keyword from my html form saved as search form to stream the keyword

Comment: You only assign a value to `searchtext` when 2 conditions are met. If either of the conditions is False, then the variable is unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `searchtext` in this line

```
tweets =api.user_timeline(screen_name =searchtext, count = 50 )
```

if request.method is not POST or the form is not valid? If any of those happen, then you're referencing the variable before it has been assigned a value.